# Remove request parameter values

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, replace

Consider a list of string/URL in a file as shown below

```
$ cat urls.txt
https://example.com/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
https://example2.com/home.php?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

I need to remove the parameter values as shown below

```
$ cat replaced.txt
https://example.com/index.php?param1=&param2=&param3=
https://example2.com/home.php?param1=&param2=
```

How can I acheive this?
I have tried several variations using **sed** that ended up replacing everything between **=** and **&** as below

```
$ sed -r 's/(=)(.*)(&)/\1\3/g' urls.txt
https://example.com/index.php?param1=&param3=value3
https://example2.com/home.php?param1=&param2=value2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
sed -r 's/(=)([^=]*)(&)/\1\3/g;s/(=)([^=]*)$/\1/'
```

where

- `s/(=)([^=]*)(&)/\1\3/g` perform substitution on firsts `param=value` pattern, but stop on `=` (to avoid greedy match)
- `s/(=)([^=]*)$/\1/` substitute last pattern

Comment: perfect. thanks for the solution and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command

```
sed  -e "s/[a-z]*[0-9]\&/\&/g" -e "s/[a-z]*[0-9]$//g" filename
```

output

```
https://example.com/index.php?param1=&param2=&param3=
https://example2.com/home.php?param1=&param2
```